# Nersutie Advanced Saved Search

Tags: netsuite

I'm new to Netsuite. I have a task of creating a saved search to display the three columns from the custom record. First Client, then Superclass and lastly from the superclass,client group I want to display the count of records having status "Wiped or Destroyed". I have grouped the record based on superclass and client successfully. Now I am experiencing problems to display the count of records having status = "Wiped or Destroyed" in the third column. I need someone to tell me how exactly it could be done?

[screen-shot of result tab in saved search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl1Mf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a text formula with a case statement to achieve this:

```
CASE WHEN {status} = 'Wiped or Destroyed' THEN {internalid} END
```

Set the Field to "Formula (text)" and the Summary Type to "Count".